# Get Data from NameApi using google apps script?

Tags: json, api, google-apps-script

I am trying to get the data for a specific name using [NameApi](https://www.nameapi.org/en/developer/) and following its [documentation](https://www.nameapi.org/en/developer/manuals/rest-web-services/53/web-services/name-matcher/) but could not find any guidance. Here is the code which I am trying to run:

```
function TestNameApi() {

  const apiKey = "###"; // Please set your API key.
  var url = "https://api.nameapi.org/rest/v5.3/parser/personnameparser?apiKey=" + apiKey;

  var Name = {
    "context": {
      "priority": "REALTIME",
      "properties": []
    },
    "inputPerson": {
      "type": "NaturalInputPerson",
      "personName": {
        "nameFields": [{
          "string": "BRANDYN KRAMER",
          "fieldType": "GIVENNAME"
        }]
      },
      "gender": "UNKNOWN"
    }
  }

  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(Name)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
  Logger.log(response);

}
```

I want to get the following data for the inputted name:

> ```
> 1. SURNAME    
> 2. GIVENNAME  
> 3. GIVENNAME2
> 4. QUALIFIER  
> 5. GENDER 
> 6. STATUS
> ```

When I run this code, I only get this error:

[image: Error]

Kindly can you guide me on what am I doing wrong in order to get this right?  Thank you.

Comment: In your showing document, it seems that you want to use "Name Matcher". But, in your script, the endpoint is different from "Name Matcher". And also in your title, you say `Get Data from NameApi`. Can I ask you about the detail of your actual goal? Because I think that the request body is required to be modified for the method of API you want to use.

Comment: Please first follow the JSON example as shown in the example.

Comment: @Tanaike yes, so I want to get the name from the Google sheet cell and get the associated data to that name (6 parameters mentioned in the question above) from NameApi, that is my actual goal.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `the associated data to that name (6 parameters mentioned in the question above) from NameApi`. In this case, you want to use "Name Matcher". Is my understanding correct? But, it seems that this method returns no values of `SURNAME,GIVENNAME,GIVENNAME2,QUALIFIER,GENDER,STATUS`. So, I'm worried that you might be required to use another method. How about this?

Comment: I apologize for this confusion, yes you are right.

Comment: About your updated script, the error message was changed?

Comment: yes, I changed the `Name` parameters in the script, which changed the error message.

Comment: yes, I already did, it gives output but the required parameters are not found in the output.

Comment: Maybe you should use `FULLNAME` for `fieldType`?

Comment: ok, but even if it works, that would not give the parameters I am looking for. right?

Comment: Oh, now, I noticed that the discussions have already been advanced. In this case, I would like to respect the existing discussions. So I would like to delete my answer. I deeply apologize.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however the output does not have all the parameters, can you please guide me ?

Comment: By the way, about `that would not give the parameters I am looking for. right?`, I have comented at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148141/get-data-from-nameapi-using-google-apps-script/74148424#comment130914338_74148141).

Comment: thank you for guiding me, what do you mean by another method?

Comment: I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. About `what do you mean by another method?`, I have commented on my 1st comment. From your question, I couldn't understand your expected method of the API. So, first, I would like to recommend deciding the method of API you want to use from your expected result. From your current situation, at least, it seems that Name Parser is not your expected method. By the way, I cannot still understand `the associated data to that name (6 parameters mentioned in the question above) from NameApi`. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tanaike and @idfurw suggested in the comments, I want to post answer that might be helpful for someone looking for the same thing. Changing `GIVENNAME` to `FULLNAME` solved the issue and the following modified script is able to get all the required parameters in the  JSON output:

```
function TestNameApi() {

  const apiKey = "###"; // Please set your API key.
  var url = "https://api.nameapi.org/rest/v5.3/parser/personnameparser?apiKey=" + apiKey;

  var Name = {
    "context": {
      "priority": "REALTIME",
      "properties": []
    },
    "inputPerson": {
      "type": "NaturalInputPerson",
      "personName": {
        "nameFields": [{
          "string": "BRANDYN KRAMER",
          "fieldType": "FULLNAME"
        }]
      },
      "gender": "UNKNOWN"
    }
  }

  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(Name)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
  Logger.log(response);

}
```